# Configuration inspector is reporting errors erroneously

Tags: configuration

I have a Drupal 8.9.19 I'/m trying to migrate to Drupal 9. I just did a status report, and have some configuration errors I'm trying to fix first. For example, this is from a view:

```
display.page_2.display_options.fields.field_faq_category.settings.linked
```

This view has a page 1 and attachment 1, but no page 2. Why is this being reported, and what can I do about it? Will it screw up my migration if it is left in?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Well no, it's no erroneous. Just because you don't know where it comes from doesn't mean the module is at fault. If configuration inspector is finding that configuration then that configuration exists. Why? That's something that you are best positioned to figure out because it's your site and you know the history. But to fix it, just remove that configuration if you're sure it's not needed.